# Geth on Raspberry - not able to connect

Tags: go-ethereum

I've installed a Geth full node on a Raspberry with IP 192.168.1.109 on my local network.

When I try to connect via `geth attach http://192.168.1.109:8545` it doesn't connect with the following error:

```
Fatal: Failed to start the JavaScript console: api modules: Post http://192.168.1.109:8545: dial tcp 192.168.1.109:8545: connect: connection refused
```

These are my `geth` startup variables: `--syncmode fast --cache 256 --datadir /mnt/ssd/ethereum`

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry - I forgot I had to add the `--rpc --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0` arguments. With that it's working.